# How to dynamically allocate a structure that involves a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am using a Student structure that contains three fields. I then declare in main a pointer to the Student structure. Then I pass that pointer to a function. This function counts how many lines are in a file and then dynamically allocate the Student array so it is the same size as the number of lines in the file and then read in the data into the array. I am stuck on dynamically allocating the Student array because the function parameter involves a pointer to a structure.

Because the function parameter is a pointer to a structure, would it work if I do `pointer = new Student[record];`? I do not know if that is how you would dynamically allocate the Student array to the same size as the number of lines in the file. The pointer in the function parameter is confusing me.

```
struct Student
{
string name;
double gpa[NUM_OF_QUARTERS];
double average;
};

bool fillArr(Student* pointer);

int main()
{

Student* ptr;

if (!fillArr(ptr))
    return 1;

return 0;
}

bool fillArr(Student* pointer)
{

ifstream infile;
infile.open("student_records.txt");
if (!infile)
{
    cout << "Error opening file\n";
    return false;
}   
int record = 0;
string str;
while(getline(infile, str))
    ++record;
cout << "number of lines in the file " << record << endl;
infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

pointer = new Student[record];  // Is this how you would dynamically allocate the Student array?
// after dynamically allocating Student array, read in the data from the file
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach would partly work, but I'd rather use a `std::vector<Student>` for that. If you want to be really fancy, you can use the `std::vector::emplace_back()` function to avoid the overhead of constructing a `Student` first, then copying it into the `std::vector` with `std::vector::push_back()`. You can find a really nice description and example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), which uses the type `President` instead of `Student`.

The signature should be `bool fillArr(Student *&pointer)` if you want to use the newly created array  in `main()`.

If you pass the `ptr` variable "by-value" to `fillArr()`, `ptr` in `main()` will not be changed, because `pointer` in `fillArr()` contains the value of `ptr` at the time of the function call. This happens with the function signature

```
bool fillArr(Student *pointer)
```

If you instead pass it "by-reference", `pointer` in `fillArr()` will refer to the variable you passed in `main()`. This happens with the suggested function signature

```
bool fillArr(Student *&pointer)
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach you have here will not work correctly because you're passing the pointer by value. If you want to proceed this way, change the function so that it takes the pointer by reference:

```
bool fillArr(Student*& ptr) {
   ...
}
```

If you don't do this, then you're only changing where a copy of the original pointer points, not where the original pointer itself points.

That said, I think that you're making things a lot harder than they need to be by not using `std::vector` in place of a dynamically-allocated array. It's a lot easier with `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Student> fillArr() {
    ifstream infile("student_records.txt");
    if (!infile) {
      /* error handling */
    }

    std::vector<Student> result;
    for (string line; getline(infile, line); ) {
         Student curr = /* initialize curr based on line */
         result.push_back(curr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This avoids raw pointers, only reads the file once, doesn't run the risk that the provided pointer is null, and doesn't require explicit memory management. This is more of the C++ way to do things, so I'd highly recommend it!

Comment: My teacher hasn't gone over vectors yet so I have no idea what they do unfortunately.